# Is it possible to add resistance using a push button?

Tags: digital-logic, switches

Does anyone know if this is possible to add resistance using a momentary switch/push button?
Meaning that I just want to push down on a button and go from 2 Volts down to 1 Volt.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What is the goal of your device?  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: How will adding resistance make the voltage go down? Show us the circuit that you want to add the push button to.

Comment: I have a 3.3v signal and I want to be able to lower it on the fly by just pressing a button.  I must be able to still use the 3.3v signal like normal though.  For example have a led running at full brightness then pressing a button that lowers it to a lower brightness then once released it will full brightness again.

Comment: Lowering the voltage on an LED from 2V to 1V will not lower the brightness, it will extinguish it.

Comment: Not an actual example I need it for a controller I am doing.  I'm trying to put analog inputs digitally with modifiers.

Comment: "I'm trying to put analog inputs digitally with modifiers" - You should describe in detail what you are _actually_ trying to do, and then you might get a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a push to break switch

[image]

When pushed this circuit will half the input voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. I think you can use the circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9OvvQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Although this only brings down the voltage to 1.5 V, by adjusting the resistors, you can make it work.

Comment: Well, you are technically "adding" a resist*or* and "removing" resist*ance*.. But I guess the answers can only make as much sense as the questions.. so maybe not much more you could have done

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm trying to do. I think Jlm Dearden's answer is better. Same principle but with less number of resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this captures the spirit of what you are trying to do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faoJFq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The value of R2 will depend on the value of R1 in the existing circuit and you should consider the calculate value as an approximate starting point, as Vf will be a bit lower at the lower current.

When the switch is closed, the resistor R2 diverts some of the ~2.8mA current through R1 around the LED so it is less bright.